# Factoring of exponents in Simon's algorithm

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binary, quantum-computation

In derivations of Simon's algorithm [(e.g., p. 4](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse599d/06wi/lecturenotes8.pdf)), it's often meant to be apparent that

$$(x_0\oplus s)\cdot y=(x_0\cdot y)+(s\cdot y)$$

where $\oplus$ is "direct sum modulo 2", $x_0,s,y$ are all $n$-bit numbers, and the dot products are over their bit representations.

It's not apparent to me though why this works. Why does this work and what is the intuition here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left- and right-hand sides don't have to be equal (for example,
$$
(1\oplus 1)\cdot 1=0\cdot 1=0\ne 2=1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1),
$$
but they are congruent modulo $2$.  To see this, you can expand both sides over the bit position $i=1$, $\dots$, $n$ to get
$$
\sum_{1\le i\le n} ((x_0)_i \oplus s_i) y_i=\sum_{1\le i\le n} (x_0)_i y_i + s_i y_i.
$$
Looking at each term in the expansion, both sides vanish if $y_i=0$.  Otherwise, if $y_i=1$, the left-hand side is $(x_0)_i \oplus s_i$ and the right-hand side is $(x_0)_i+s_i$.  These are both even if $(x_0)_i=s_i$ and both odd if $(x_0)_i\ne s_i$.

Another way to see the congruence is to work over the two-element field ${\Bbb F}_2$ and to take the $n$-bit numbers to be in the vector space ${\Bbb F}_2^n$ over ${\Bbb F}_2$.  Doing this makes the dot product a function from ${\Bbb F}_2^n\times {\Bbb F}_2^n$ to ${\Bbb F}_2$.  Also, $\oplus$ becomes vector addition in ${\Bbb F}_2^n$, so the congruence is reduced to the identity
$$
(x_0+s)\cdot y = x_0\cdot y + s\cdot y, \qquad \ \  x_0, s, y\in {\Bbb F}_2^n,
$$
which holds because the dot product is bilinear.

Comment: Ah. And in the context of exponents in Simon's algorithm, we are indeed modulo 2.

Comment: Yes, since $w\equiv z \pmod 2 \Rightarrow (-1)^w=(-1)^z$.

Comment: So $x+y\equiv x\oplus y\pmod 2$ — but not  $x\oplus y\equiv x+y\pmod 2$ — right?

Comment: No, both of these are true. Being congruent modulo $2$ doesn't depend on which term is written on which side of the equation. It just means that both sides give the same remainder after being divided by $2$.